# Ball Lock Corny Liquid dip tube

Tags: corny-keg

Will a liquid dip tube with wings fit any corny keg or are some made to use wingless tubes only?

Answer (score 1):

Image courtesy of: https://www.homebrewing.org/24-Curved-5-gallon-Soda-Keg-Liquid-Dip-Tube-With-Ears-Used-_p_6478.html

Just to help clarify for anyone looking at this post:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Winged dip tubes aren’t common - the vast majority of Corgy ‘Cornelius’ kegs liquid dip/sip tubes don’t have wings.

It will come down to two things:

1. The size of the inlet hole in the liquid pin or ball locked socked. I.e if this has been adapted for wings on the dip tube or not. To my knowledge no Corgy keys are adapted for wings here.
2. Whether the wings are collapsible - i.e. whether the wings are pivoted around a pin in the tube and you are able to collapse them for entry to the keg.

I’ve never seen (1) - in the case of (2) I’ve only ever seen this once and it was a custom thing. So if you already have a dip tube that you can test fits a Corgy keg but the wings and aren’t collapsible then I very much doubt you’ll find a Corgy that fits it. If however the wings are collapsible so that they pose no barrier for the dip tube entry - then all should be fine.

EDIT:
Based on the comment below I believe wings refers to the threads at the top of the dipstick. In the case both ball and pin lock Corgy kegs will use the exact same dip tube. The only difference between ball and pin lock kegs is the mount and the connector.

Comment: I have several ball lock corny kegs and most of them have what I have been calling winged dip tubes. These wings are on both the gas and liquid tubes and in order for them to fit into the keg the port on the keg has two grooves that the wings slid into. The wings are not retractable they are just raised portions right under the flange on the upper end of the tube and this allows the bent liquid tube to be positioned to locate the tube end in the center depression in the keg..

Comment: You are right - I think the issue here is terminology: I’ve never heard these referred to as “wings” - I have always head these referred to as threads. By your definition it is correct and yes **all kegs come with this.** The wings I have seen were at the end of the dip tube nozzle (going into liquid) having a wing and or platform disc over the top that forced extraction from the bottom of the vessel. This is the basis for my explanation and understanding. So your wings being my threads - yes all Corgy kegs will fit it. I’ll amend my answer.

Comment: Actually I should have said ears rather than wings. Most suppliers refer to these raised sections as ears, don't know why I called them wings.